# Access to fetch has been blocked by CORS policy. It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: spring-boot, fetch

So I'm building a react app that fetches JSON data from a spring boot rest api built by me.

Here is the code for the fetch method:

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`http://localhost:8080/students`, {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }

        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => this.setState({students: data}));

        console.log(this.state.students);
    }
```

However when I run the program it gives me an error saying:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/students' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: there are many existing SO questions dealing with Spring and CORS issues.  if none of them worked for you, please add more detail here as to why.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% familiar with Spring Boot, but the general solution to this problem is to make sure your service responds with an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header that matches the origin (localhost in your example) if it is not the same origin as your service.

Adding `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` would do it for your development purposes. In production, you probably want to be more specific with which origins are actually allowed.

Have a look at this resource for more information about CORS: https://enable-cors.org/

It is the same origin policy implemented in your browser that is causing this. It specifies that a browser should allow scripts in one web page to access resources on another, but only if they are from the same origin. If they are not, you can specify that they are allowed by specifying the header I mentioned above. You may also need to specify allowed verbs and headers as well, depending on what you're doing.